# Can I use Apple Compressor software to convert mkv files to mp4

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, conversion, mac, mkv

I use Final Cut Pro X. I am planning to buy Compressor software too which gives me options in exporting my video. Can this same software be used for converting mkv files to mp4 because Final Cut Pro X doesn't support mkv files.

Comment: Try Handbrake, VLC or a smart tool for Mac lie DumboFab.

Answer (score 1):

No Compressor does not take .mkv files. At least not my 4.5.1 version.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/features.php) can do this, and it's free:

> Supported Input Sources: Handbrake can process most common multimedia
> files and any DVD or BluRay sources that do not contain any kind of
> copy protection.
>
> Outputs:
>
> File Containers: .MP4(.M4V), .MKV and WebM Video Encoders: H.264 and
> H.265 (Including hardware acceleration support), MPEG-4 and MPEG-2,
> VP8, VP9 and Theora Audio Encoders: AAC / HE-AAC, MP3, FLAC, AC3,
> E-AC3, Opus and Vorbis Audio Pass-thru: AC-3, E-AC3, FLAC, DTS,
> DTS-HD, TrueHD, AAC, MP3 and MP2 tracks